# How to parse a CSV with multiple key-value pairs?

Tags: java, csv, parsing

I have a CSV in this format:

**"Account Name","Full Name","Customer System Name","Sales Rep"**

**"0x7a69","Mike Smith","0x7a69","Tim Greaves"**

**"0x7a69","John Taylor","0x7a69","Brian Anthony"**

**"Apple","Steve Jobs","apple","Anthony Michael"**

**"Apple","Steve Jobs","apple","Brian Anthony"**

**"Apple","Tim Cook","apple","Tim Greaves"**

...

I would like to parse this CSV (using Java) so that it becomes:

**"Account Name","Full Name","Customer System Name","Sales Rep"**

**"0x7a69","Mike Smith, John Taylor","0x7a69","Tim Greaves, Brian Anthony"**

**"Apple","Steve Jobs, Tim Cook","apple","Anthony Michael, Brian Anthony, Tim Greaves"**

Essentially I just want to condense the CSV so that there is one entry per account/company name.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String csvFile = "something.csv";
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";

List<String> accountList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> systemNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> salesList = new ArrayList<String>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) 
    {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] csv = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            accountList.add(csv[0]);
            nameList.add(csv[1]);
            systemNameList.add(csv[2]);
            salesList.add(csv[3]);

        }
```

So I was thinking of adding them all to their own lists, then looping through all of the lists and comparing the values, but I can't wrap my head around how that would work. Any tips or words of advice are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing your requirements you can get a better idea of the data structures to use. Since you need to map keys (account/company) to values (name/rep) I would start with a `HashMap`. Since you want to condense the values to remove duplicates you'll probably want to use a `Set`.

I would have a `Map<Key, Data>` with

```
public class Key {
    private String account;
    private String companyName;

    //Getters/Setters/equals/hashcode
}

public class Data {
    private Key key;
    private Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<String> reps = new Hashset<>();

    public void addName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
    }

    public void addRep(String rep) {
        reps.add(rep);
    }

    //Additional getters/setters/equals/hashcode
}
```

Once you have your data structures in place, you can do the following to populate the data from your CSV and output it to its own CSV (in pseudocode)

```
    Loop each line in CSV
      Build Key from account/company
      Try to get data from Map
      If Data not found
        Create new data with Key and put key -> data mapping in map
      add name and rep to data

    Loop values in map
      Output to CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I probably would create a class, let's say "Account", with the attributes "accountName", "fullName", "customerSystemName", "salesRep". Then I would define an empty ArrayList of type Account and then loop over the read lines. And for every read line I just would create a new object of this class, set the corresponding attributes and add the object to the list. But **before** creating the object I would iterate overe the already existing objects in the list to see whether there is one which already has this company name - and if this is the case, then, instead of creating the new object, just reset the salesRep attribute of the old one by adding the new value, separated by comma.

I hope this helps :)